# Windows 7 Folder broken creation glitch

Tags: windows, filesystems

I wrote a program in python that created folders. I'm having difficulty removing some of the folders due to this glitch.

I already figured out how to prevent it. But for the folders already created are irremovable. I get this error message when trying to delete them.

> Could not find this item. This is no longer located at ... Verify the items location and try again [Try Again][Cancel]

I tried removing the folders by typing `dir /x` into a console
and then using the shorthand of the folder name with the del program. ex: `del FOLDER~1`
But that only works some of the time.

The only difference between the broken and non broken folders is the space at the end of the folder name when creating.

**How to make a broken directory:**

```
mkdir "broken folder /"
```

**How to make a normal directory**

```
mkdir "normal folder/"
```

Extra info:
The folders can still be used. The files inside can be deleted. Just not the folder itself or its parent folder.

When this glitch occurs in python using `os.mkdir` it also creates two directories with the exact same name. Only one can be deleted regularly.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a python script that fixes all the broken folders. So if anyone hits this issue. Hope this helps. Just drop into whatever folder is full of broken folders. Its kind of poorly made. But gives an idea about what you need to do.

```
from glob2 import glob
import os
import shutil

#find all folders
folders = glob("./**/")

# for each folder check if they exist and rename them to have an A at the end of their name.
for fold in folders:
    if fold != ".\\":
        if os.path.exists(fold):
            name = fold.rsplit("\\", 2)[-2] + "A"
            print(name)
            print(fold)
            os.rename(fold, name)
```